# I have an object Company and List of Employee objects, I want to create a List of Company objects which will contain the single Employee Object

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Company` class having following structure

```
public class Company{
    private Long id;    
    private Employee employee;
}
```

And I have a list of Employee objects `List<Employee>`and the `Employee` class is as below

```
public class Employee{
    private Long id;    
    private String name;
}
```

The requirement is, I want to create the List of Company which will contain all single - single employee according to the above structure.

as `List<Company> company`.

What is the best practice to achieve this ?

Comment: The Employee object in Company class should be a List right?

Comment: @SivaRahul Nope, I wanted to kind of flatten the `Company` object so the only one `Employee` will be in the `Company` thus I will create `List<Company>` to accommodate all of the `Employee` objects

Comment: Where is or How is the data saved?

Comment: Please share your **code attempt** and explain the specific problem you've encountered (for now, it's unclear).

Comment: How does your related to the Spring framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming constructors and getters.

- creat a list of Company
- iterate over employee list adding employee to companyList.

```
List<Company> companyList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Employee e : employeeList) {
    companyList.add(new Company(e.getId(), e));
}
```

Or if you prefer a stream solution.

```
List<Company> companyList = employeeList.stream()
       .map(e-> new Company(e.getId(), e))
       .toList():
```

Depending on your use case it may be wise to create a new employee object from your original. If the employee class is immutable this will not be necessary. This is only shown for the stream solution.

```
List<Company> companyList = employeeList.stream()
       .map(e-> new Company(e.getId(), new Employee(e.getId(), e.getName())))
       .toList():
```